# Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array in SSRS VBA Code

Tags: vba, reporting-services

I have written below Code in SSRS Report and calling it from expression as =Code.convertCode(Parameters!ProcessingStatus.Value,"Reject,Fail")).Value , but on previewing report I am getting the error : "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array"

```
Public Function convertCode(ParamValues As String, findString As String) As String()
Dim SrcArray() As String
Dim FndArray() As String
Dim DstArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
SrcArray() = Split(ParamValues, ",")
FndArray() = Split(FindString,",")
For k = LBound(FndArray) To UBound(FndArray)
For i = LBound(SrcArray) To UBound(SrcArray)
    If (InStr(SrcArray(i), FndArray(k)) > 0) Then
        ReDim Preserve DstArray(j) As String
        DstArray(j) = SrcArray(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Next k
arr = DstArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function you have

```
arr = DstArray
```

which should be

```
convertCode = DstArray
```

Not sure if that's already the problem.

Note: `Option Explicit` would prevent this error.

Comment: I think this change worked for me but SSRS expression still throwing error. I am using Join(Code.ConvertCode(Parameters!ProcessingStatus.Value,"Reject,Fail"),",") in the SSRS expression. M i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Still the same error, or a different one?  I have never used SSRS, so probably can't be of any further help.

Comment: No No.. VB problem is solved now. It seems somethign wrong with SSRS expression. Anyways, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not declaring the first dimension in your arrays.

```
Dim SrcArray() As String
Dim FndArray() As String
Dim DstArray() As String
```

Should be:

```
Dim SrcArray(10) As String
Dim FndArray(10) As String
Dim DstArray(10) As String
```

Or whatever the number of the Array you'll need.

The error message indicates that the number of indices you have (none) is less that what you need (variables I, k, j).